# SSL SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER on internal company network, REST service

Tags: rest, ssl, ssl-certificate

Long story/short:  I'm on an internal network, with a REST service we created that runs on a server with some sort of self-signed certificate.  I'm writing code for the front end of the application on another server.

I hit this with my javascript typeahead function.  The REST call that answers the typehead is failing with a security warning `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`.  I understand why, it's because the client can't find the cert in its root store.

Other than to get the REST server to install a corporate/verified certificate is there any other way around this?  Is there some way to get my Javascript application to say "**hey I don't care if whatever I'm talking to is unknown**" (?)

Before anyone yells at me, this is all on a hardened internal network with zero access to or from the big bad internet.  Thanks...

Comment: [You could add the self-signed certs to your browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).

Comment: Right, but every user of my application will have to do that.  It seems a little awkward.

Comment: Do you control all systems in that internal network? Maybe you could try http://serverfault.com/questions/12323/how-do-i-deploy-an-internal-certificate-authority (perhaps you should specify the front end platform).

Comment: Thanks...I'm using jQuery/AJAX so I think I need to go down a path of setting `rejectUnauthorized: false` (if possible), in the AJAX call...I'm looking into it now...

Comment: No I mean what is the target browser (Chrome / Firefox / Edge / Safari / ??) and OS (Win10 / Win7 / macOS / Ubuntu / ??)

Comment: Yes, all of those ;-)

Answer (score 0):

alright...I think I'm finding out the answer is 'no way, no how'.  In the AJAX call diagnostics, it clearly shows the header `Access-Control-Request-Headers` as set to "rejectunauthorized" - and from what I'm reading there is no way for an application to override that, due to basic security precepts.